# SQL query ordering when order is in same table

Tags: sql

I have a two tables, one that contains basic resource info, with columns and values like:

[image]

And a separate table of exta associated values with columns and data like:

[image]

What I am trying to do is write a SQL query that will join both and produce a result that is ordered by the "order" key, like so:

[image]

I am not sure how to make my join work so that I can both pull the location values and then SORT by the order values from that same table.

And before you ask, no I can't redesign the db schema, I have to work with this. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.RESOURCE_NO
       ,t1.NAME
       ,t2.VALUE
       ,t3.VALUE -- Included so that you can "see" the value
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.RESOURCE_NO = t2.RESOURCE_NO AND t2.[KEY] = 'location'
 INNER JOIN table2 t3
    ON t1.RESOURCE_NO = t3.RESOURCE_NO AND t3.[KEY] = 'order'
 ORDER BY t3.VALUE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This general idea should work (tested under Oracle):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
    JOIN TABLE2 TABLE2_ORDER
        ON TABLE1.RESOURCE_NO = TABLE2_ORDER.RESOURCE_NO AND TABLE2_ORDER.KEY = 'order'
    JOIN TABLE2 TABLE2_NONORDER
        ON TABLE1.RESOURCE_NO = TABLE2_NONORDER.RESOURCE_NO AND TABLE2_NONORDER.KEY <> 'order'
ORDER BY
    TABLE2_ORDER.VALUE
```

In plain English:

- Join to both order and non-order values.
- An then sort only by order values.

*(Of course, this assumes there is **exactly** one 'order' value per TABLE1 row. If that is not the case, this query will either "multiply" or "erase" rows.)*