# SQL query select and ordering all from same table with key/value pairs

Tags: sql

OK, I have a single table with keys and values that I need to query and order from that looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Let's say I want to pull all  distinct items (resource_no) that are in the webcategory of "dog" (and any other values) and order them by "order" in ascending order so that my result is this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to query my table to allow this...I have tried inner joins but they do not seem to work...can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag.

Comment: You have not yet accepted an answer for your previous question related to these tables [sql-query-ordering-when-order-is-in-same-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350640/sql-query-ordering-when-order-is-in-same-table)

Comment: lol, this is work, not homework.

Comment: and previous question accepted, thanks...but then I realized that the above was really the query I needed, so sorry for the similar questions and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kind of tricky to read when it's all in separate rows n the same table, but this should do it for the values you have now. If you're thinking dynamic columns, you'll need to go database specific procedures.

```
SELECT a.RESOURCE_NO, a.value webcategory, b.value location 
FROM      resources a
LEFT JOIN resources b ON a.RESOURCE_NO=b.RESOURCE_NO AND b.key='location'
LEFT JOIN resources c ON a.RESOURCE_NO=c.RESOURCE_NO AND c.key='order'
WHERE a.key = 'webcategory' AND a.value='dog'
GROUP BY RESOURCE_NO
ORDER BY c.value
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0647/4).

Comment: One follow up...any idea how to correct for potential null values in the order field?

Comment: @Stephen Do you mean a NULL in the value field of a row which has the key "Order", or a missing order row entirely? Also, correct in what way? Would you like it sorted first or last or...?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  resource_no
,       'dog'
,       location
from    YourTable
where   webcategory = 'location'
        and resource_no in 
        (
        select  resource_no
        from    YourTable
        where   webcategory = 'dog'
        )
order by
        location
```